# Looking for a short story about a submerged house

Tags: horror, story-identification

New here and hoping you can help me locate an eerie short story I read in the early 90's. Here's what I recall:

**A man sees something sticking up out of a lake and swims out to investigate. Turns out to be the roof of a house. There is a hole in the roof and he lowers himself down into the house. Even though it's almost completely underwater, the water inside is only a few inches deep. It's implied there is something sloshing around in the corner. He gets back on the roof and a rowboat slowly approaches.**

Again, I read this short story in an anthology (paperback) sometime in the early 90's. The editor (?) said something before the story about how writing the story scared the author. I don't remember all the details, but I do know it gave me some real chills.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: http://edwincrowe.com/heavy-rain/ Very long shot.

Comment: "eerie" tone aside, was there a sci-fi/fantasy element to the story? from the description you've posted, it doesn't sound like this work would be on-topic here.

Comment: Possibly also the story "On 202", was part of "The Years best horror stories X", by Jeff Hecht (1981). Also part of the Twilight Zone, but I can't find a synopsis.

Comment: @phantom42 1. Inasmuch as this is a story-ID question, we don't know what story it's about, and have no way of knowing if it's sci-fi/fantasy or not. Once the story is identified we will be in a position to make that determination. 2. If you're going to close questions on the grounds that something is "not sci-fi/fantasy", it would be nice to link to the site's **definition** of "sci-fi/fantasy". I haven't been able to find it myself.

Comment: i didn't vote to close it, so settle down there.